# how can check Runtime.exec(cmd) is completed or not

Tags: java

how can check  Runtime.exec(cmd) is completed or not?

It is running but how can I check command is executed or not in java program?

If I used process to check then it is blocking current thread. If I stopped running program then Runtime.exec(cmd) is executing. What should I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873830/in-java-determine-if-a-process-created-using-runtime-environment-has-finished-ex

Comment: If I closed current thread then cmd is executing.

Comment: What do you mean by closing current Thread ?

Comment: From what i understand (your last sentence is not very clear), you mean that if you don't use waitFor then your program exits. This does not mean that the runtime is not executed, simply that your java Thread did not wait for your command to complete and ended.

Comment: I have written Runtime.exec(cmd)  in class "A" and now calling this class in  class "B". If I stopped B class execution then class "A" is running otherwise it is not running.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`Process`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) instance can help you manipulate the execution of your runtime through its InputStream and Outpustream.

The process instance has a [`waitFor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--) method that allows the current `Thread` to wait for the termination of the subprocess.

To control the completion of your process, you can also get the `exitValue` of your runtime, but this depends on what the process returns.

Here is a simple example of how to use the `waitFor` and get the process result (Note that this will block your current Thread until the process has ended).

```
public int runCommand(String command) throws IOException
{
    int returnValue = -1;
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( command );
        process.waitFor();
        returnValue = process.exitValue();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Note that this will block your current Thread until the process has ended. I don't want to block current thread then what should I do?

Comment: Then you should do the work in another Thread. Have a look at the java tutorial about concurrency. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/