# How to startActivity after clearing app data?

Tags: android

When "Logout" button clicked, app is clearing all data.

```
private void deleteAppData() {
    try {
        // clearing app data
        String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        runtime.exec("pm clear " + packageName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How to set some listener for runtime.exec finish? When execution finished I would like to open Splash activity. Now app is closing only.

Question: how to start activity after runtime.exec completed?

Comment: After clearing the data start splash activity.

Comment: use asynctask and start activity in onPostExecute method

Comment: yeah, how to identify I finished clearing? This is what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @Rahul, good idea. I will check this out

Comment: Check this -
[how can check Runtime.exec(cmd) is completed or not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31020807/6244429)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this in `OnDestroy` or `onStop()` of the logout activity because the `startActivity(i)` will be called after runtime clears the data and then the application will transition into the other activity.

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after you start a new activity, using startActivity, make sure you call finish() so that the current activity is not stacked behind the new one.

```
 Intent mIntent = new Intent(mContext,MainActivity.class);
finishAffinity();
startActivity(mIntent);
```

Comment: Question is about how to identify when runtime.exec finishes

Comment: Normally will clear the prefrence value after clearing the prefrence value it will redirect to the particular activiy the same way he can do.Also you have mentioned "When execution finished I would like to open Splash activity. Now app is closing only."For that am answering

Comment: In addition to preferences, I have SQLite database and Internal storage files . That's why I want to delete all data

Comment: Try to read this links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31020705/how-can-check-runtime-execcmd-is-completed-or-not, 
                      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873830/in-java-determine-if-a-process-created-using-runtime-environment-has-finished-ex